# how do i fix 'int' object is not iterable error

Tags: python, integer, palindrome

Hello i'm new in python and im stuck with this error. Can you explain me what am i doing wrong? Also is the math import necessary?

The consept is to find if the word is palindrome.

Here is my code:

```
  #palindrome
import math #do i need it?

wrd=input("give me a word ")
key=False

length=int(len(wrd)/2 +1)

for i in length:
    for j in length:
        if i==j:
            pass
        else:
            key=True

if key==False: print("palindrome")
else: print("not palindrome")
```

Comment: You need to use `range(length)`.

Comment: You want to iterate over the word and its reversal, not two lists of integers. Also, you appear to be trying to iterate over every possibly *pair* of indices; `i == j` is guaranteed to be false at some point.

Comment: If you do iterate over `range(length)`, then you want to compare `wrd[i]` and `wrd[length - 1 - i]`.

Comment: The range function is what you need. `range(length)` will give you an iterable object.

Comment: A `string` is just a list of characters in Python. To check if a word is a palindrome, is as simple as do:  `word == word[::-1]`

Comment: @DanielHao yes i figured it out, but i dint know your way so thanks for the info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to import math

Use `range()` function -

```
wrd=input("give me a word ")
key=False

length=int(len(wrd)/2 +1)

for i in range(length):
    for j in range(length):
        if wrd[i]==wrd[j]:
            pass
        else:
            key=True

if key==False: print("palindrome") # This is generally bad practice
else: print("not palindrome") # Use indentation so that it is more readable
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, although i figured out that my code is totally wrong xD